# PostgreSQL: preventing sql injection on multiinsertion

Tags: json, postgresql, database-performance, database-security

I'm looking for the **fastest** way to parse, validate and insert data in table(**Postgresql 9.3)**.

The data is an json-array which contains 1..N items.

```
[{"name":"a","value":"1"},{"name":"b","value":"2"}]
```

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE logs
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text ,
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT "log_Pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

For that i have stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_logs(v json)
  RETURNS  integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    sql text;
    i json;
    logs_part_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO logs_part_id id from another_table_with_that_id where some_condition.

    sql = '';
     FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(v)
      LOOP
      sql = sql||'insert into logs_'||logs_part_id ||'
        (name, value)
         values( ' ||quote_literal(i->>'name')||' , ' ||quote_literal(i->>'value')||' );';

      END LOOP;
    raise notice '%',sql;

    EXECUTE sql;
    return 1;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

(function returns integer as a response status)

Function call:

```
select * from insert_logs('[{"name":"a","value":"1"},{"name":"b","value":"2"}]'::json);
```

Actually the "insert.." statement is quite bigger - 15 columns to insert and aparently some of them should be checked in order to prevent sql injection.

**Question**:
Is there any way to rewrite this stored procedure in order to improve performance?
Should I use prepared statements?

**EDIT.**

The reason i build sql string because the table name is unknown because of the tables partitioning.  The table name format is: logs_**id** where id - int which is obtained just before insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you building an SQL multi-statement string  then `EXECUTE`ing it at all?

Just:

```
  insert into logs (name, value)
  values( i->>name , i->>value );
```

There's no need for explicit quoting because `i->>name` is a `text` value that's inserted as a bound parameter into the `insert` by PL/PgSQL. It's never parsed as SQL.

If you *must* build the statement dynamically (e.g. varying table name, per comment) use `EXECUTE ... USING` with `format`:

```
  EXECUTE format('insert into %I (name, value) values( $1, $2 );', 'logs_'||log_partition_id) 
     USING i->>name , i->>value;
```

in your case

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need to build multistatement string because table name is not fixed. It depends on some parameter. I edited my 1-st post

Comment: @xardas Good detail to include first time around, especially since your function didn't actually show that at all. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to speed up your query, [json_populate_recordset()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) does exactly what you need:

```
insert into logs
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::logs, '[...]')
```

As, for SQL-injection: you should always use prepared statements, or at least execute your sql with parameters sent separately (f.ex. with [`PQexecParams()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html) if you use libpq directly).